# If $A$ and $B$ form a separation of $X\setminus Y$, then $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Suppose $Y\subseteq X$ topological spaces. $X$ and $Y$ are connected.
>   Let $A$ and $B$ be a separation of $X\setminus Y$ (this means that $A$
>   and $B$ are disjoint open sets such that $A\cup B=X\setminus Y$). Then
>   I need to show both $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected.

I thing I need to prove it by contradiction. So let us assume $K$ and $M$ form a separation of $Y\cup A$. From here i need to show that this assumption leads to either of $X$ and $Y$ being disconnected. I can't show that so easily. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note that if X is connected and A and Y both are proper subsets of X.Now any continuous map from X to a discrete topology must be constant.Y and A being proper subsets of X;f will take the same constant value.So any two point map from Y union A is constant,hence connected.

Comment: That's an elegant method. The fact that Continuous map from connected space to discrete topology must be constant and vice versa, is so helpful